# Is this fluffy thing a rabbit?

Tags: is-the-order-a-rabbit

In *Gochuumon wa Usagi Desuka?*, Tippy, the creature on top of Chino's head, is introduced to be a rabbit.

Is it in any possible way a rabbit in real life, or is it just another [RidiculouslyCuteCritter](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RidiculouslyCuteCritter)?

[image]

Comment: Please only use one tag per series.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ: I use all those tags to facilitate creating synonyms, since this series is currently not available for tagging here.

Comment: But you have enough rep to not only create tags but also create [tag synomyns](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Comment: +1; I had the exact same question when I watched the series. Plus, it's nice to see Gochiusa get some attention on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tippy is an [Angora rabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angora_rabbit). A popular pet amongst French royalty in the mid-18th century and in Europe in the later part of the century.

A picture of a White English Angora rabbit from Wikipedia:

[image]

It was also officially confirmed from [this magazine illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keqQ4.jpg) (Japanese) in the Q&A in the lower left corner.

> **Is rabbit actually an item on the shop's menu?**
>
> Although *Tippy*, **an Angora rabbit**, is kept as a pet at *Rabbit House*, and in episode 1, Cocoa ordered for a rabbit out of ignorance, there is no such thing on the menu, since Tippy is obviously not for sale (lol). [...]